# how to groupby but counsecutively only

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

> i have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'costs': [150, 400, 300, 500, 350], 'month':[1, 2, 2, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

> i want to use groupby(['month']).sum() but first row not to be
> cobmined with fourth and fifth rows so the result of costs would be
> like this

```
list(df['costs'])= [150, 700, 850]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby((df.month != df.month.shift(1)).cumsum())
    .agg({"costs": "sum", "month": "first"})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   costs  month
0    150      1
1    700      2
2    850      1
```

Comment: can u please break down this block of code

Comment: @EhabFaisal With `(df.month != df.month.shift(1)).cumsum()` I create integer series by which I *group* the dataframe (each difference in the month increases the integer). Then simply use `sum` to get sum of costs.